# Avoid Name Reservation for Unused Abstract Optional Function Arguments

Tags: c++, optional-parameters, rule-of-three

I have a solver class template, whose solve-routine may be called with an optional ostream.

Under a specialization of said class template, the ostream is never used.

## Question

Why can't I literally remove the character-sequence "fdsa" from the minimum example below, and have it achieve the same behaviour as what I expected analogously from the code `foo`?, namely that:

1. I define `foo` in one single place.
2. I need no label for the second argument of `foo`.
3. I can call `foo` with either one or two arguments.

## Minimum Example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
class OptionalWrapper{
    T* p;
public:
    const bool is_empty;
    OptionalWrapper(void):is_empty(true),p(NULL){}
    OptionalWrapper(T& r):is_empty(false),p(&r){}
    T& operator()(void){ assert(!is_empty); return *p; }
    T const& operator()(void)const{ assert(!is_empty); return *p; }
};

template<typename Tfloat>
struct Solver{
    // ... lot of other code
    void compute(Tfloat&x, OptionalWrapper<std::ostream> o=OptionalWrapper<std::ostream>() ){
        if(!o.is_empty) o()<<"solver<float>::compute("<<x<<");\n";
    }
};

template<>
struct Solver<double>{
    // ... lot of uncorrelated specialized code
    void compute(double&x, OptionalWrapper<std::ostream> fdsa=OptionalWrapper<std::ostream>() ){
        std::cout << "solver<double>::compute("<<x<<");\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    //
    float xf = 1;
    double xd = 2;
    //
    Solver<float> sf;
    Solver<double> sd;
    //
    sf.compute(xf,std::cout);
    sf.compute(xf);
    //
    sd.compute(xd,std::cout);
    sd.compute(xd);
}
```

Has it to do something with the rule of 3/5, that I cannot just replace `OptionalWrapper<std::ostream> fdsa=OptionalWrapper<std::ostream>()` with `OptionalWrapper<std::ostream> =OptionalWrapper<std::ostream>()` ?

(Remark: Defining the function outside of the class specialization body will result in acceptance by GCC and the above code as is without "fdsa" will be accepted by CLANG, MVSC, ICX, and ZIG. So maybe there is indeed not much insight to gain from the question. My apologies for only finding out now.)

## What I expected

That I can use the same principle of overloading as with

```cpp
int foo(int x, int=0){
    return 2*x;
}
int main() {
    foo(1);
    foo(2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

and not need to provide a label for `y`, the second argument. Basically I would assume that to the compiler the type of the second argument should not even matter because it will not be dealt with by the function body anyways.

Comment: If it's never used, why is it in the function arguments? 
`int foo(int x, int){ return 2*x; }` won't compile if I say `foo(1);`.

Comment: You can omit the parameter **name** from the method if it is not used, but the parameter is still there and you have to pass some argument when calling the method.

Comment: @Darius. Good point on the foo! So the ostream is in the function arguments because the user may write it there. Think of an application that is used for debugging in Tfloat=SensitivityAnalysisNumber and release with double, but the user regardlessly may or may not have attached an ostream to look at the convergence behaviour when Tfloat=SensitivityAnalysis.

Comment: @wohlstad. Can you clarify how I can omit the parameter name from the method definition? Because that is exactly my question.

Comment: `void compute(double& x, OptionalWrapper<std::ostream>) { ... }`. But why does it bother you to specify the parameter name?

Comment: @wohlstad. But that in GCC 13.02 will require the second argument. The example with foo works with either one or two arguments. This is the behaviour I seek to achieve for OptionalWrapper as well.

Comment: @wohlstad. The exact error message I receive is ``error: no matching function for call to 'Solver<double>::compute(double&)'``

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, removing the parameter name is not removing the parameter itself, so you still need to supply the argument for it when calling the method. Which is why I thought it will not help you ... but what's wrong with having the parameter with the default value like you did (this will enable to call it without supplying the 2nd argument) ?

Comment: @wohlstad. Probably we misunderstand each other. So what I like to do is for Solver::compute to achieve the same behaviour as foo. I.e.: 1) I need one single scope for definition, 2) I provide a name for the first variable and no name for the second variable, and 3) I can call the routine with either one or two arguments.

Comment: @kaisong yes I'm afraid I don't understand the issue. If you want a method with an optional 2nd parameter (i.e. with a default value) I don't understand what's wrong with the solution you have. Why are you bothered by the name of the parameter ?  BTW - MSVC accepts having a default value without a parameter name: `void compute(double& x, OptionalWrapper<std::ostream>  = OptionalWrapper<std::ostream>()) {...}` but I'm not sure it's guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @wohlstad. I have tried in godbolt that MSVC, CLANG, GCC, and ICX accept the code with foo. But at least GCC does not compile it. My motivations are that 1) I run out of dummy variable names and 2) I thought I gain insight on the language by understanding what makes my type different from int.

Comment: You should have provided error message of your (failed and shown) attempt.

Comment: @kaisong did you try to add a space after the `>` as suggested by the answer below ? BTW - _"I run out of dummy variable names"_ - you can use the same dummy name in multiple methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OptionalWrapper<std::ostream>=OptionalWrapper<std::ostream>()` has parsing issue, you need extra space:

`OptionalWrapper<std::ostream> =OptionalWrapper<std::ostream>()`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Kffnxsrn9).

else `>=` is considered as greater_than, (similarly to old `>>` issue to close a double template).

Comment: Oh, I noticed that. Hence why I had written in the minimum example the comments on "... lof of other code". Because, yes, when you define the function outside of the class body then it works. But I cannot make sense of it. Why would I have to write it outside of the class. This just makes it less readable to me.

Comment: I define the function inside class body... Your issue is "parsing tokens", extra spaces fix the issue.

Comment: @kaisong - The issue is with `>=`, which doesn't fit in the declaration, as it looks like a comparison.

Comment: Ouh, I removed the ``o`` from the Tfloat's compute. I am so sorry! My bad.